# Is it usable to put the shopping cart icon in the app bottom bar?

Tags: usability, mobile, ux-field

I am designing online grocery  mobile application, I do not know what is the best location to put the shopping cart icon in the app bar or in the bottom tab bar.
Much of applications and website put the shopping cart in the top left of the screen but some have redesigned the app and put it in

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have to include some widely used functionnalities like the cart system, I think it is in your interest to stick to the [mental model](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mental-models/) of your users.

**Where do your users think the cart is whenever they have added an item to their cart?**

**Cheaper option** is to browse a couple of apps similar to yours and notice where did they chose to place it.

**Better option** is to run a design walkthrough test on 3 to 5 participants and specifically ask this question when they have just added an item. The discussions you will have with these tests will help you understand your users better and make a rationale design choice.

I would also recommend including some **[micro-interaction](https://codyhouse.co/gem/add-to-cart-interaction/) to hint where the item is going**.

It is difficult to give a straight answer as it depends on various elements (webapp or native, mobile system, type of shopping...). Yet, I hope I have managed to give you a clear idea on how to get these answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will make it easier for users if you stick to the convention that 'most' sites use.

A site with more traffic will have a bigger influence on the convention than a site with a smaller traffic.

Comment: This is not necessarily true in all cases - **Most** people use Windows yet OSX is just as easy (if not easier) to use but uses very different conventions for a lot of major UI components.

Comment: If you put someone who is used to Windows in front of OSX their productivity will go down and they will go through a period of stress as they learn a new interface. Things are only easy when you know how.

Comment: You said "stick to the convention that 'most' sites use" not "stick to the convention that most of the sites *your users are familiar with* use" - Two very different concepts and the second one could prove very difficult to measure accurately. I was just trying to point out that 'convention' isn't always correct.

Comment: I agree with the clarification.  However it requires knowing quite a lot about your users (or if you don't yet have users, your potential users)